# Vector Spaces problems and axioms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm currently stuck in two vector space problems. I feel as though the signs and my lack of knowledge throw me off. I am not aware of what $\boxplus, \boxdot$ mean in the first problem (should I just think of them as addition and multiplication). Same happens with problem 2. Should I assume $\oplus, \odot $ mean addition and multiplication. Please help, thank you.

Problem 1: In ${R}^2$, consider the following operations:

$(x_1, y_1) \boxplus (x_2, y_2) = $(max {$x_1, x_2$}, max { $y_1, y_2$ })

$\alpha \boxdot (x,y) = (\alpha * x, 0)$

is ${R}^2$ with these operations a vector space? If your answer is negative, list all the vector spaces axioms that fail to be satisfied and explain why; otherwise prove that all the axioms are satisfied.

Problem 2: In ${R}^2$, consider the following operations:

$(x_1, y_1) \oplus (x_2, y_2) = (x_1 + x_2, 0) 
\alpha \odot (x,y) = (\alpha * x, y)
$

is ${R}^2$ with these operations a vector space? If your answer is negative, list all the vector spaces axioms that fail to be satisfied and explain why; otherwise prove that all the axioms are satisfied.

Comment: Yes, they means addition and scalar multiplication (but not the usual ones, and this notation is introduced to be  less confusional than the ordinary `+` and `·`).

Comment: "I am not aware of what $\boxplus,\boxdot$ mean in the first problem..."  It literally defines what $\boxplus,\boxdot$ mean right there in the problem statement...  That is what the lines are doing where the symbols first appear.  They define $\boxplus$ to be the binary operation over $\Bbb R^2$ such that if you combine two elements of $\Bbb R^2$ via $\boxplus$ the result is as written.  Namely, $(x_1,y_1)\boxplus (x_2,y_2) = (\max\{x_1,x_2\},\max\{y_1,y_2\})$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a vector space $V$ over $F$ is a set together with an operation that takes two elements of $V$ and gives you an element of $V$, which we call the “sum” of the two elements; and an operation that takes an element of $F$ and an element of $V$ and gives you an element of $V$, which we call the “scalar product”.

These operations need not be related to what we *usually* call “sum” and “product”. In order to avoid possible confusion with operations we *usually* call sum and product, we may want to use different symbols.

For example, we *usually* define “the sum of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$” to be the vector $(a+c,b+d)$, where the sum is the usual sum of real numbers. But we don’t *have* to define it this way; we could try to come up with a different way of defining it. So in order to prevent us from confusing this new way of “adding” pairs with the *usual* way, we use a different symbol, so as to keep it separate. Since $+$ denotes the usual sum of real numbers, instead we will use a symbol which is sufficiently similar to remind us it’s supposed to be a “sum”, but sufficiently different to remind us it is **not** the *usual* sum. Common choices are $\boxplus$ and $\oplus$.

So you *define* the way to “combine” two vectors $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ to get a new vector, called “$(a,b)\boxplus (c,d)$”, using the definition
$$(a,b)\boxplus(c,d)\text{ will represent the pair }(\max{a,c}, \max{b,d}).$$
This may or may not satisfy the conditions we need to have for this way of “combining” vectors to work as the sum in a vector space... you are being asked to check whether it does.

Similarly, $\boxdot$ is just a definition of a potential “scalar multiplication” that you need to check to see whether it satisfies the requirements to be the scalar multiplication of a vector space.

And again, same thing with $\oplus$ and $\odot$ in problem 2: these are the *definitions*, and you should check if these operations “work” to get a vector space.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation it was very concise. I'll try to work the problems now.

Comment: @Josue: If you find an answer helpful, remember to upvote it (you may be unable to do so until you get enough reputation); if your query has been answered, remember to accept the answer you find most satisfying, so that the question can be marked as “answered” in the site.

Comment: I will as soon as I hit the reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

The sign $(x_1,y_1)\boxplus (x_2,y_2)$
between the two pairs of numbers defines an new kind of addition 
same with the sign $\boxdot$ in  $\alpha\boxdot(,)=(,0)$a new kind of multiplication by a scalar is defined, you have to find out if with these new definitions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you have still a Vector space, if not, what axioms do not hold.